# How executed code block Science mode in Pycharm

Tags: python, machine-learning, pycharm

Like Spyder, you can execute code block. how can i do in Pycharm in science mode. in spyder you use

`# In[]`

How can i do this in pycharm

Comment: PyCharm 2018.1 introduces "Code Cells" - I think [this is the closest you'll get](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2018/02/pycharm-2018-1-eap-4/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pycharm use code cell. you can do with this

'#%% '

Answer (score 1):

you can just import numpy to actvate science mode.

`import numpy as np`